# awk string concatenation not working

Tags: bash, awk

I have this file

```
*PADS2000*
*PART*
C1               C2012
C10              C2012

*NET*
*SIGNAL* B2B_12V
F1.2 TC1.1
CNB2.88 U2.1
*SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1
U9.M8 U9.H1
U5.6 C24.1
*END*
```

and I want to convert it to look like this (list signal name and all the connected part.pin names in a single line).

```
*SIGNAL* B2B_12V F1.2 TC1.1 CNB2.88 U2.1
*SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1 U9.M8 U9.H1 U5.6 C24.1
```

The awk script I wrote is like this.

```
BEGIN{print "========================="}
(d || f ) && (/*SIGNAL*/ || /*END/) {print "HAHAHA : " xline}
/*SIGNAL*/{kept=$0; f = 1; xline=$0; next}
f {print kept; f = 0; d = 1; print; xline=xline " " $0; next}
d {print; xline=xline " " $0}
```

The output is like this.

```
=========================
*SIGNAL* B2B_12V
F1.2 TC1.1 
CNB2.88 U2.1 
 CNB2.88 U2.1 AL* B2B_12V
*SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1
U9.M8 U9.H1 
U5.6 C24.1 
 U5.6 C24.1  NAL* DDR3_VREF1
*END*
```

What is wrong? (It looks like the strings are overwritten every time when it should be concatenated.)

EDIT : I later found that this works as I wanted in Cygwin. my CentOS shell seems to have something making it weird. If I run it on Cygwin, it runs like below as I expected. (I'll come to my shell problem when I have time.)

```
$ awk -f why.awk in.dat
=========================
*SIGNAL* B2B_12V
U24.2 TC1.1
CNB2.88 U2.1
HAHAHA : *SIGNAL* B2B_12V U24.2 TC1.1 CNB2.88 U2.1
*SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1
U9.M8 U24.H1
U5.6 C24.1
HAHAHA : *SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1 U9.M8 U24.H1 U5.6 C24.1
*END*
```

Comment: you only want one `print` statement in your code, which always outputs a trailing `\n` char. The rest should be `printf(...)` which do NOT include a trailing `\n` char. Good luck.

Comment: Regular expression `/*SIGNAL*/` is illegal since * is an RE meta-character. You should escape the *.  `(/\*SIGNAL\*/ || /\*END/)`

Comment: @cdarke, but /*SIGNAL*/ seems to work in awk.

Comment: @ChanKim My version gives an error, and yours only *appears* to work.  For example, the pattern `L*` does *not* mean "L followed by a *", it means "zero or many L's".  Try `awk '/SIGNAL*/{ print }' <<< 'SIGNA'`, it finds a match!  `awk '/SIGNAL\*/{ print }' <<< 'SIGNA'` does not (which is correct).  I have no idea what your version is doing with the leading *, but since that is invalid I suspect it ignores it.

Comment: After a bit of playing it appears that `gawk` does allow a leading asterisk to match an asterisk, but `awk` does not.  Your `awk` is probably a symbolic link to `gawk`.  However, both `gawk` and `awk` behave the same way for the trailing asterisk.  This might explain the difference on Cygwin and CentOS (CentOS uses a symbolic link to gawk).

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @cdarke I tried placing \ before * in the RE but it's the same. (As you said, awk in CentOS was gawk). Because I used /*SIGNAL*/, the first * was ignored and it searched pattern including SIGNA which was not any issue in my case because there is no other places including pattern SIGNA except the one I see. The strange phenomenon is as if the string concatenation is not done correctly. When I assign xline = xline + $0, it appears the second part is overwriting to the existing xline pattern from the beginning as far as second string's length. The remaining characters are left intact. Any clue?

Comment: You don't concatenate strings in `awk` using `+`, you just put them together: `awk '{xline = xline $0} END{print "<" xline ">"}' gash.txt`.  This is why Perl and PHP introduced the '.' string concatenation operator.  The comma you often see in `print` statements actually uses the variable `OFS`, Output Field Separator, which defaults to a space.

Comment: @cdarke I know that. you see I 'm doing what you are saying but it' not working in my CentOS shell somehow.

Comment: @cdarke Hi, my problem was because the input file was of DOS file format. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322387/awk-string-concatenation-not-working-2-shell-setting-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dit it using gawk on Cygwin but it also works on my CentOS 6.7 shell. But there is some problem with my CentOS shell as I added on the EDIT above.
For anyone's benefit, I attach my gawk script here :

```
BEGIN{print "========================="}

(f || d ) && (/*SIGNAL*/ || /*END*/) {
f=0; d = 0; n = asort(xline);
printf "%s ", kept;
for (i=1;i<=ix; i++){
printf "%s ", xline[i];
}
printf "\n";
ix = 0;
}

/*SIGNAL*/{
kept = $0; f = 1; next}

f {
f = 0; d = 1;
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    xline[ix] = $i;
    ix = ix + 1;
}
next}

d {
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    xline[ix] = $i;
    ix = ix + 1;
}
next}
```

Output :

```
*SIGNAL* B2B_12V CNB2.88 TC1.1 U2.1 U24.2
*SIGNAL* DDR3_VREF1 C24.1 U24.2 U24.H1 U5.6
```

EDIT :
I later found that this strange phenomenon was because the input text file was from DOS(Windos). See Adam Katz's answer in [awk string concatenation not working 2 (shell setting error?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322387/awk-string-concatenation-not-working-2-shell-setting-error).

Comment: See my comment on the REs you are using.  This throws errors on OS X.  It's not the shell by the way, `awk` has nothing to do with the shell, it is its own language.

Comment: pluse-uno for struggling thru to your own working answer. Wish your commentors well! Good luck to all.

Comment: please see my EDIT above. Thanks!