# awk string concatenation not working 2 (shell setting error?)

Tags: shell, awk

I have this strange phenomenon I don't understand. I guess I'm missing something important in awk. I want to cumulatively concatenate the whole line to a string called 'c' when there is a line containing SIGNAL. The string starts with a concatenation of 'a' and 'b' which works fine.

file `in.dat`:

```
SIGNAL Hello1!
```

file `tt.awk`:

```perl
BEGIN    { a = "a"; b = "b"; c = a b; }
/SIGNAL/ { c = c " " $0; }
END      { print c; }
```

when I do `awk -f tt.awk in.dat` I get (as expected):

```
ab SIGNAL Hello1!
```

now I change `in.dat` to:

```
SIGNAL Hello1!
SIGNAL Hello2!
```

Then I do `awk -f tt.awk in.dat` again and get:

```
 SIGNAL Hello2!1!
```

I expected to see:

```
ab SIGNAL Hello1! SIGNAL Hello2!
```

I am doing it on my CentOS shell (with bunch of settings in my `~/.cshrc` file). I checked these on my Cygwin shell and it works normally as I expect. Something is wrong with my CentOS shell setting. What could it be?

Comment: I get exactly the expected result (`ab SIGNAL Hello1! SIGNAL Hello2!`) with your code. What are your shell settings?

Comment: Does `in.dat` have DOS line endings?

Comment: chk for DOS line endings with `cat -vet file`. If you see `^M$` at the end of lines, use `dos2unix file`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with DOS line endings (as noted by Etan Reisner in the comments above).  Your second version of `in.dat` uses `\r\n` for line breaks and `awk` can't deal with that.

Using your same `tt.awk` code:

```
$ echo "SIGNAL Hello1\!\nSIGNAL Hello2\!" |awk -f tt.awk
ab SIGNAL Hello1! SIGNAL Hello2!
$ echo "SIGNAL Hello1\!\r\nSIGNAL Hello2\!" |awk -f tt.awk
 SIGNAL Hello2!1!
```

Wondering what this is really doing?  In UNIX, [`\r`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) resets the position in line to the leftmost place but does *not* send you down a line (that's what [`\n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) does).  DOS interprets `\n` as going down a line but not resetting to the leftmost position while UNIX takes the `\r` as implicit.

Here are some experiments to illustrate what's going on:

```
$ echo "SIGNAL Hello1\!\r\nSIGNAL Hello2\!"
SIGNAL Hello1!
SIGNAL Hello2!
$ echo "SIGNAL Hello1\!\rSIGNAL Hello2\!"
SIGNAL Hello2!
$ echo "ab SIGNAL Hello1\!\n SIGNAL Hello2\!"
ab SIGNAL Hello1!
 SIGNAL Hello2!
$ echo "ab SIGNAL Hello1\!\r SIGNAL Hello2\!"
 SIGNAL Hello2!1!
```

Pay special attention to the last two items.  `awk` strips the `\n` for you, but retains the `\r`, so the first line prints as `ab SIGNAL Hello1!` and then the `\r` is applied, and the second line  `signal Hello2!` is written *on top of* that first line.  The first line's final two characters (`1!`) remain because the second line wasn't long enough to overwrite them.

Now that we know the issue, we can fix the code:

```perl
BEGIN    { a = "a"; b = "b"; c = a b; }
/SIGNAL/ { gsub(/\r/, ""); c = c " " $0; }
END      { print c; }
```

This removes all `\r`s from lines that are added to `c`.

Comment: Thanks! I started with a big file that I brought from windows. As far as the file is from Windows, it seems to stay in DOS format no matter how much I edit it. Just now, I started the test in linux and it works just fine(I thought I tested with in.dat made in linux but maybe it was my mistake).